# Azure Blob Storage Pre-Signed Url Features

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As my experiences, AWS S3 has a feature called pre-signed. Which allows me to issue a url with specific expiry time to access.

I cannot find any details about that on Azure official website.

So, does anyone know if Azure Blob Storage can support pre-signed url features?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> does anyone know if Azure Blob Storage can support pre-signed url
>   features?

Yes, Azure Blob Storage supports that. It is called `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` in Azure Storage. A SAS enables you to provide time-bound, permission-limited access to storage resources. You can create a SAS on either a blob container/blob (`Container Level SAS`) or all blob containers/blobs in an account (`Account Level SAS`).

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature.

Comment: I just called azure customer support center, the engineer told me they doesn't have the feature... Thanks anyway, man. I will figure out by your instruction.

Comment: I believe they’re mistaken. Can you please ask them specifically about Shared Access Signature?

Comment: SAS is not functionally equivalent to pre-signed URIs.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi Would you mind elaborating your comment?

Comment: Check this github ticket out for more detail: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/issues/170

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi After reading the GitHub issue I would say that it depends on what you mean by “equivalent”. For example, people migrating from AWS will only need the concept of “container” (corresponding to AWS “bucket”) and “blob” (corresponding to AWS “object”), so lacking separate management for “block” isn’t related in this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The azure presigned URL can be generated. It's like Generate the blob url and generate SAS token. Append the bloburl with sas token and that's the presigned URL. I was using azure c++ sdk.
To get blob url: GetUrl()
To get Sas token = GenerateSasToken().