# Is it possible to do a "pass through" upload mechanism?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC upload tool for our end-users. The final destination for the file involves a 3rd party service where exposing the direct upload URL would potentially leave it open to abuse. So I'm looking at introducing a "middle-man" API to filter upload requests.

Traditionally we've stored the file in Azure blob storage after receiving it from the browser before calling an Azure function to upload the file as a separate process. I'm looking to streamline this - is it possible (and wise) to make a pass through process wherein the user uploads through a browser and our API server simultaneously sends it to the 3rd party service?

Comment: Sounds like you should check into the WebClient class.

Comment: Why not use short-lived object-specific signed URLs?

Comment: @Russ thanks, that looks like an avenue worth exploring

Comment: @John I'm afraid I'm not experienced enough to know what you mean. Are you proposing some sort of hash value appended to the 3rd party upload URL?

Comment: Sure, your API would basically act as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm proposing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233010/azure-blob-storage-pre-signed-url-features and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature