# Secure media sharing of paid media files using Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, .net-4.8

I'm developing C# web API for web site where I want to share paid media files, I stored media files to Azure blob storage. Currently when someone pay for some book, video, audio and s/he wants to access to that media I make SAS token for every access and I am not sure is that best way. Could someone help me and suggest some better way for this? That solution need to use Azure services.

If I wasn’t clear enough. Example:

1. On my site there is some video with price 5$.
2. User buys that video.
3. When s/he click to play video I make SAS token for onetime access(expire in 5 sec) and return URL for that video and media player retrodicting video. If user refresh web page I make new SAS token again and return new URL etc...

Comment: `I make SAS token for onetime access(expire in 5 sec)` What if the file takes longer than 5 seconds to download?

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233010/azure-blob-storage-pre-signed-url-features may be a good place to start reading.

Comment: @mjwills When media play start reproducing video, I don't need SAS token until the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design question, and please note that it cannot be answered in one response and without knowing business requirements end to end.

But, I would give a suggestion here. You can use [User Delegation SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#revoke-a-user-delegation-sas) for this.

> A SAS secured with Azure AD credentials is called a user delegation
> SAS. Microsoft recommends that you use Azure AD credentials when
> possible as a security best practice, rather than using the account
> key, which can be more easily compromised. When your application
> design requires shared access signatures, use Azure AD credentials to
> create a user delegation SAS for superior security.

*Below is the timeline of steps to be followed:*

1. If user makes a transaction and pays for a video, assign a [User Delegation SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#revoke-a-user-delegation-sas) based on his credentials. Save this as a secret in your DB against your user's record (**Again, design for this should be done based on discussion with the architect**).
2. Create a backend job which [Revokes User Delegation Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/revokeuserdelegationkeys) if the time period of the purchase is expired and renewal is not done.

Comment: User Delegation SAS is for transferring media to the blob storage. I don't need that. I currently have Account Name and Account Key, using them I generate a SAS token for the user. What I need approximately is on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233010/azure-blob-storage-pre-signed-url-features), but unfortunately Azure doesn't support that.

Comment: Sure, you can use a SAS using your Account name and key. As 'Stopped Contributing' said, ' A SAS enables you to provide time-bound, permission-limited access to storage resources. ', what is the problem with that approach? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: At the end, for every access to media I make SAS token, and that is ok. I wanted to skip calling API every time when user want to access to media. Thank you alot for your help.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you can use SAS also.

Comment: Yes, I used that from start, I asked here just to know if is there better solution.